# Why is NSCoding unable to decode an object once saved properly?

Tags: swift, core-data

Here is the full class I am saving in core data as a transformable.

```
public class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {
    public var imageData: Data
    public var title: String
    public var keywords: [String]
    public var date: Date

    public init(imageData: Data, title: String, date: Date, keywords: [String])  {
        self.imageData = imageData
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
        self.keywords = keywords
        super.init()
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(imageData, forKey: "imageData")
        coder.encode(title, forKey: "title")
        coder.encode(keywords, forKey: "keywords")
        coder.encode(date.timeIntervalSince1970, forKey: "date")
    }

    public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        self.init(
            imageData: (coder.value(forKey: "imageData") as? Data) ?? Data(),
            title: (coder.value(forKey: "title") as? String) ?? "",
            date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (coder.value(forKey: "date") as? TimeInterval) ?? Date().timeIntervalSince1970),
            keywords: coder.value(forKey: "keywords") as? [String] ?? [])
    }

}
```

I am able to save these object in core data successfully, but when I fetch these objects, it crashes in the method -> **public required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder)**

Because the coder can not find a value for the key.

Here is the error I get,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageData.

I have tried different transformer's, I've tried creating my own.

I have tried saving it as binary data, and I have also tried to create a relational database instead but nothing seems to work.

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key value coding-compliant properties must be marked as `@objc dynamic`

```
@objcMembers
public class Item: NSObject, NSCoding {
    dynamic public var imageData: Data
    dynamic public var title: String
    dynamic public var keywords: [String]
    dynamic public var date: Date

...
```

`@objcMembers` is a global directive for all properties

And you should use the proper API to **decode** the objects

```
public required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.init(
        imageData: (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "imageData") as? Data) ?? Data(),
        title: (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "title") as? String) ?? "",
        date: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "date")),
        keywords: aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "keywords") as? [String] ?? [])
}
```

Comment: CoreData: fault: exception raised during multi-threaded fetch [<NSKeyedUnarchiver 0x2801ce640> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageData. ({
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = "<NSKeyedUnarchiver: 0x2801ce640>";
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = imageData;
})